# phpmyadmin, MariaDB 10 and Point columns

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, geospatial, opengis

Trying to edit a column of a table in MariaDB using PHPmyAdmin v5.1.1 gives me trouble.
It saves the column as binary and I need to edit the whole row in order to be able to edit it as text. Even doing so, when choosing Edit/Insert next to the appropriate field, I get this copied:

```
'POINT(0 0)',0
```

However this is not compatible with MariaDB 10. The only thing that works so far is using a raw query for updating the field like this:

```
UPDATE `locations` SET `point` = POINT(1, 2) WHERE `locations`.`id` = 169;
```

My question is, isn't there a way of updating the field through the UI of PHPMyAdmin instead of running manual queries?

Trying to be more specific. This is how the column looks like in PHPMyAdmin:

[image: This]

And this is how it looks like when editing the row:

[image: this]

Note that because its WKB, it cant be edited directly. However when adding to the point field this:

```
POINT(1, 1)
```

PHPMyAdmin changes it to:

```
'POINT(1, 1)'
```

And it doesnt work.

Also the comma is needed otherwise MariaDB throws an error:

```
#1416 - Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
```

Comment: graphical? i can't understand your quetion

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: I removed the phpmyadmin tag. It's just the client program. Using it is like using a Firefox tag on a question about Stack Overflow because you viewed it with that browser.

Comment: The question is specifically about phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this looks like a bug in the PHPMyAdmin for the newer versions of MySQL and MariaDB. It is described in this very recent article [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1583/what-is-causing-mysql-error-1416-cannot-get-geometry-object-from-data-you-send-to-the-geometry-field#:%7E:text=This%20query%20will%20throw%20the,version%20of%20MySQL%20or%20MariaDB.)

Indeed a fix is already deployed and will be available in [PHPMyAdmin 5.1.2](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/pull/17074)

Answer (score -1):

If you use the [ST_PointFromText()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-wkt-functions.html#function_st-pointfromtext) function you can take Well-Known Text [WKT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/wkt/) format text input you show in your example. and turn it into the Well-Known Binary [WKB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/wkb/) format suitable for stashing in a WKB format column in a table.  Something like this.

```
UPDATE locations 
   SET point = ST_PointFromText('POINT(1 2)') 
 WHERE whatever
```

Modern versions of [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-wkt-functions.html#function_st-pointfromtext) and [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/st_pointfromtext/) both have this.

Notice that `POINT(1 2)` doesn't have a comma separating the two numbers. Use commas between points, like this.

```
LineString(1 1, 1 2, 2 2)
```

If you want WKT (the text format) use [ST_AsText()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/st_astext/). That will make it possible for text-based client programs to display your geometric data.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(point)
  FROM locations
 WHERE whatever
```

Comment: Thanks but as I said, I also have a way to do that using a query. I wonder why the latest version of PHPMyAdmin doesn't work through user interface for doing the same.